# Trying to implement string in a file name location

Tags: c#

how to include a string in the file location in c sharp

string is the File

```
string File = @File;
path = @"C:/Temporary/@File.pdf";
```

Comment: `"C:/Temporary/" + File`? Windows uses backslash, by the way

Comment: Or using string interpolation: `$"C:/Temporary/{File}"`. It's generally not recommended you use reserved keywords though (hence the need to use the @ sign).

Comment: what is `@File`?

Comment: @JuanR `File` is no reserved keyword, just a name of a namespace. It's completely fine to name a variable `File`, with or without leading `@`. I suppose the *actual* reason for the verbatim is to avoid a self-reference of the `File`-variable: `string a = a` will certainly not compile, but not because `a` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I was referring to `File`. It's reserved in the sense that it's an existing class name. It's generally preferable to avoid using names that collide with other things to avoid confusion. Nothing stops you from using it. That's what the `@` is for, but it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in Windows those should be `\` characters, rather than forward slashes `/`. But then, once you have the `@File` value in a regular string variable you can use interpolation:

```
string file = @File;
path = $@"C:\Temporary\{file}.pdf";
```

And in a mixed environment, where this might also run on a system expecting the other slash direction, you can check which is right:

```
string file = @File;
var slash = Path.DirectorySeparatatorChar;
path = $"C:{slash}Temporary{slash}{file}.pdf";
```

But the **best** way is usually to `.Combine()` the path:

```
string file = @File;
path = Path.Combine("C:", "Temporary", $"{file}.pdf");
```

And often code will use a mix, where the base path is computed once and then later on other values can be appended:

```
string basePath = Path.Combine("C:", "Temporary");

// ...


string file = @File;
path = Path.Combine(basePath, $"{file}.pdf");
```

Finally, note how I changed the name of the variable to avoid creating a conflict with the `System.IO.File` type. You'll save yourself a **ton** of trouble by avoiding that kind of conflict in your code.

Comment: What if the @file is a variable

Comment: @Pinku The code in this answer already accounts for that, but you could also include it in the interpolated string directly. And again: **you should avoid variable names that need the preceding `@` character.**